# Why PMD suggests to declare the JSONArray as final

Tags: java, pmd

I ran PMD on my source code which is somewhat this way

```
JSONArray jsarray_com = new JSONArray();
```

Later i am adding some elements to the jsarray_com this way

```
jsarray_com.put("One");
jsarray_com.put("Two");
```

Now coming to the question what PMD is suggesting is that declare the JSONArray as final ??

Could you please let me know what advantage will one get if it declared as final

When I made the changes this way

```
final JSONArray jsarray_com = new JSONArray();
```

the code is working fine .

Comment: Can you please share a fuller snippet, as well as the text of the suggestion you're getting from PMD?

Comment: I'd suggest just to switch off this diagnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PMD has detected that `jsarray_com` is never reassigned, so it's suggesting to add `final` to the declaration to make this fact explicit. When you see `final`, you immediately know that `jsarray_com` will always reference the same object. It makes the code slightly easier to follow, but you are free to ignore the suggestion.

Using `final` when possible might also help the JVM optimize your code, although this last point is not that relevant. In fact, most JVMs are able to figure this out without any input from the user, in the same way PMD does.

Note that declaring a variable as `final` does not prevent you from modifying the object through methods like `.put()`. So, for instance, you can do this:

```
jsarray_com.put("foo");
```

but not this:

```
jsarray_com = anotherarray_com;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean the [LocalVariableCouldBeFinal](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/optimizations.html) rule in PMD: This is just an optimization issue: Because PMD has noticed that your variable is assigned just once, it suggest you could declare it as final, because it would produce an optimal code.

However, I agree with [Tagir Valeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856258/tagir-valeev)'s comment: It was probably an old optimization technique, but in modern JIT compilers, it makes no difference. I usually turn this rule off (or, at least, ignore it). It is a good practice to declare final members and final classes, but to declare final locals or parameters... psch!

Comment: That's actually wrong: JIT compiler is smart enough to see by itself whether the variable is assigned just once. Probably that was reasonable optimization for Java 1.4, but not now.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. I was just quoting what PMD is doing, but I edited my comment to add your point.